# Compare 2 tables fields and if they match, copy primary key over to form relation POSTGRESQL

Tags: postgresql

This shows some sample data that I might have (real data is much larger):

table1:

`date      forename       surname      PK
 1998      john           harry
 1928      fred           kale`

table2:

`date      forename       surname    PK
 1998      john           harry       2
 1928      fred           kale       98`

I need to compare table2 with table1 and if they match then I need to add the same PK from table2 into table1 to form a relation.

EDIT: I would like to add that in table1, the "people" can appear twice but only once in table2.

Comment: You can't have multiple rows with the same primary key value.

Comment: That's okay in my database, you'll just have to trust me on this one. It only needs to be a primary key in table2.

Comment: Then I assume you mean a foreign key? What have you tried?

Comment: Yes sorry, it's a foreign key. I didn't know where to start so I haven't tried anything yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PostgreSQL:

```
UPDATE table1
SET FK = table2.PK
FROM table2
WHERE 
   table1.date = table2.date 
   AND table1.forename = table2.forename
   AND table1.surname = table2.surname
```

SQL Server

```
UPDATE t1
SET FK = t2.PK
FROM
  table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2
     ON t1.date = t2.date 
        AND t1.forename = t2.forename
        AND t1.surname = t2.surname
```